# Custom XAML styles for night mode

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-8

I have a XAML app (specifically a Windows 8 XAML app) that I want to add a night-reading mode for. This will be a setting a user can switch, and it will change the theme colors to be white on black, instead of my standard black on white.

My question is, how can I do this? I'd like to do it actively (meaning, the moment the user switches, I show the new version, and not have to make them restart them app).

I'm still fairly new to XAML, so I don't know if I'm overlooking something. Currently, I'm routing all my styles to go through staticresources in my themes file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a [theme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.resourcedictionary.themedictionaries.aspx).  Basically it's a set of globally available resources that you can swap out as a set.  See [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-control-and-app-494840f7/sourcecode?fileId=63706&pathId=2050113133) for an example.

Edit:  I guess you can't change it without restarting: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/f91a11d6-6e56-4978-8acd-21ae9f3c3a6e/

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? I know there are themes, but my question is more of 'is it possible to dynamically change between themes at run time and have the app auto-update to it' :)